# Indentation of multi-line arrays within braces?

Tags: indentation, cc-mode

Currently in C mode, contents of a muli-line arrays are aligned with the brace. eg:

```
const unsigned int array[4] = {
                               A,
                               B,
                               C,
};
```

Is there a way to configure `cc-mode` to use a single indentation in this case?

```
const unsigned int array[4] = {
    A,
    B,
    C,
};
```

e.g. if indentation is set to 4 spaces.

Comment: This also affects enum definitions..

Answer (score 2):

The following setting makes brace lists use a single indent:

```
(c-set-offset 'brace-list-intro '+)
```